# HTML -Card text not wrapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a html card following this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_cards.asp). Then i added to my page (which uses bootstrap 3.0). However, the text is not wrappering like it does in the tutorial. Does anyone know why this is or how to fix this?

Picture

[image: Example]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD9dy.png

Html snippet

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <card [visable]="obj.one" [width]="100" [image]="obj.two" [header]="project.manager?.name" [content]="obj.four"></card>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label ">
                        Project Name
                    </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" [value]="project.name" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label ">
                        Project Number
                    </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label ">
                        Project Creator
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label ">
                        Team
                    </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label ">
                        Team ID
                    </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label ">
                        Team Manager
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
                        <div class="container">
                            <h4><b>Project Details</b></h4>
                            <p >One team of students collected data from a                                 consumer Internet website with automobile specificatins.The summary slide shows                 the results of their linear regression analysis on car engine horsepower and average miles per gallon (MPG) ratings</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

css

```
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
}
```

Comment: Remove the container class from the div containing that text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap `container` is conflicting with with "tutorial" `container`.

Use a special container class for the card...

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
      <div>
            <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
                  <div class="card-container">
                        ..
                  </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>

.card-container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
}
```

Comment: Oh dude, i cant believe i didn't think about that. Yup ill mark answer in 11 minutes.

Comment: Great. It's amazing how many SO questions come from poor guidance on W3schools.

Comment: This is correct... pro tip: NEVER NEST Bootstrap `.container`'s